# Removing unwanted lines in text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

All I need is the `sed` or `awk` code to remove the even numbered lines in a text file. Nothing fancy I just need to remove irrelevant data on the even lines of a text file.

Answer (score 6):

Simply:

```
sed 'n;d' file
```

for even lines, and

```
sed '1!n;d' file
```

for odd lines.

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can also use this syntax:

Odd:

```
sed '1~2d' file
```

Even:

```
sed '2~2d' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the GNU specific sed syntax, and also for the introduction of `1!` operator Stephane :)

Comment: "1" is an address restriction. I think the "!" operator here [inverts the "n"](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-32). (Don't go to the next line; delete this one.)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove said lines of unwanted text by like so

```
sed -i '/[REGEX]/d' <FILE>
```

Where `[REGEX]` is a regular expression that matches the unwanted line of text, and `<FILE>` is the name of the file you want to remove the text from.  You can nest delete (`//d`) commands like so:

```
sed '/[REGEX]/d ; /[REGEX]/d ; /[REGEX]/d'
```

Here's an example:

```
echo "a" > file ; echo "abcd" >> file 
sed -i '/^a$/d' file
cat file # => abcd
```

---

If your version of `sed` doesn't support the `-i` option, you can use to following to the same effect.

```
cat file | sed '/[REGEX]/d' > file_2 && cat file_2 > file && rm file_2
```

---

#### A word to the wise

Redirecting the output of `cat file` right back into `file` will not have the desired effect.  It will in fact, truncate `file` completely, that is it will completely *erase* `file`.

So **don't** do this:

```
cat file | sed '/[REGEX]/d' > file
```

Comment: If you use a fairly recent GNU sed you can avoid the redirect, cat and rm with `sed -i '/[REGEX]/d' file`. That solution also relies on the even lines matching `[REGEX]`.

Comment: @DravSloan, _fairly recent_ is 2002 here (sed 3.95).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution:

For deleting odd line:

```
awk 'NR%2==0{ print $0 > "infile" }' infile
```

For deleting even lines:

```
awk 'NR%2{ print $0 > "infile" }' infile
```

Note that above commands deletes the related lines **in-place** from `infile` input file, so be careful you write the output in to the same input file.

You can write them into another separate file like as following:

This will create the `EvenLines` file contain even-number of lines:

```
awk 'NR%2==0{ print $0 > "EvenLines" }' infile
```

And this one will create the `OddLines` file contain odd-number of lines:

```
awk 'NR%2{ print $0 > "OddLines" }' infile
```

Answer (score -1):

---

```
sed '0~2d' file
```

---

This command is used to delete the even lines in the files.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! We like answers to be a bit more comprehensive here. Could you edit and include an explanation?